# Generating unique ids that are not repeated in hypothesis

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

I want to generate unique ids that aren't repeated. I tried to use `st.uuids()`.

This is my code

```
class MyTest(<class that inherits from unittest.TestCase>)
  @hypothesis.seed(0)
  @hypothesis.settings(derandomize=True)
  @hypothesis.setting(use_coverage=False)
  @hypothesis.given(st.uuids())
  def test(self, test_id):
    logging.info('test_id %s', test_id)
    logging.info('self.ids %s', self.ids)
    if test_id in self.ids:
      logging.info('SHOULD NOT BE HERE')
    else:
      logging.info('HAPPY')
      self.ids.append(test_id)
```

However, I get 1 repeat. Any tips on how to avoid repeats?

```
test_id 5bc8fbbc-bde5-c099-4164-d8399f767c45

self.ids [UUID('e3e70682-c209-4cac-629f-6fbed82c07cd'),
UUID('1ee77147-c7be-894d-5073-79c36d3c338d'),
UUID('734007f9-e3b1-3a59-bac6-78e47a6e8c0f'),
UUID('97343ee7-03f6-c7c0-d787-3a75e0040c6d'),
UUID('12193edd-6aac-c6b6-8caf-d66c89075de6'),
UUID('ea37c9e0-a3f9-3fe5-0b68-afbaab69828e'),
UUID('e13a37b0-f328-3835-4a40-cfc1142acbf7'),
UUID('36a3a379-28ca-876f-6b68-1fc4502323be'),
UUID('cbf97494-2dae-a0f6-43a5-5203d7fdc239'),
UUID('94012b2d-1221-006b-266c-7dcefecc417e'),
UUID('e05fccb4-9d81-b03f-4f0c-7c859a0af299'),
UUID('c6148cd8-b446-bc4f-7fea-3b29b7b93ee5'),
UUID('cd613e30-d8f1-6adf-91b7-584a2265b1f5'),
UUID('d95bafc8-f2a4-d27b-dcf4-bb99f4bea973'),
UUID('5af6e118-6344-2432-9707-6fb276cfc8bf'),
UUID('c1a4bbe2-f5bc-beed-3a7c-be792b90ac94'),
UUID('01457085-dc53-6b6a-b47f-3aefd7768cc6'),
UUID('6beb5a8d-f4b1-3663-a3e3-c900e848b602'),
UUID('21636369-8b52-9b4a-97b7-50923ceb3ffd'),
UUID('b8a1abcd-1a69-16c7-4da4-f9fc3c6da5d7'),
UUID('5bc8fbbc-bde5-c099-4164-d8399f767c45')]

SHOULD NOT BE HERE
```

It's weird cause that I can see that id in the log statements just above this one.

I wonder if the `@cacheable` or `@defines_strategy_with_reusable_values` has anything to do with it
https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/blob/cedbafe52934e5f710be41c51044388ef3047850/hypothesis-python/src/hypothesis/strategies.py#L1868

Answer (score 2):

Unique IDs are not repeated *within a test*.  However, Hypothesis may try to pass any particular value as an input in many individual iterations of the test - without this, it would be impossible to detect flakiness and many common errors would be much more difficult to find.

You should ensure that your tests do not set or depend on any external mutable state, or use the `setup_example` and `teardown_example` methods to clean up appropriately.

This is a fundamental invariant for shrinking as well as example generation.